# What is "Preverifying..." step in gradle build and why does it take so long?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

When enabling the following settings in `build.gradle`:

```
minifyEnabled true
shrinkResources true
```

the build of release now takes a very long time (previously 1 min, now takes > 1h). I can see in the gradle console that the step taking most of the build time is `Preverifying...`:

[image]

What is this step? Can I make it faster?